# How to make Webpack build on Express server started

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm new to React and Webpack. I have `webpack.config.js` like this:

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        'user': ['./client/User/index']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/static'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                query: { cacheDirectory: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    node: { fs: 'empty' }
};
```

And this is my `app.js` entry of Express server:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import session from 'express-session';

const app = express();

import config from './webpack.config';
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/assets', express.static(`${__dirname}/static`));

app.use('/', require('./server/route/index'));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Our Blog is listening on port 3000...'));
```

Webpack does not build and yields any bundle in the `dist` folder as configured. It can only build when I use `webpack-cli` command. Besides, in my `html` document, I include the bundle as `<script src='/static/user.bundle.js'></script>`. I thought this must be the correct path, because it will map `/static` to `dist` folder on local machine as configured where the bundle is exactly located after build. But it keeps sending me 404 error due to resource not found. May you help me solve this?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack creates the file in memory. so you can't see it as per [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/).

> webpack-dev-server doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory and serves them as if they were real files mounted at the server's root path. If your page expects to find the bundle files on a different path, you can change this with the publicPath option in the dev server's configuration.

I suspect because you did not specify it as `production` mode that's why it's not writing to `dist` folder. Also you need to use [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware). Here's an [example](https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/webpack-express-examples/blob/master/webpack-dev-middleware-example/server/index.js) for you how to use it

I hope this helps.